# Sorting sides of n triangles according to the area

Tags: c, bubble-sort

Given n triangles, with sides a,b,c print them in the same style by sorting them from the smallest to the largest.
Complete problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/small-triangles-large-triangles/problem

In the solution, we have a structure named as Triangle. It has 3 integers a,b,c. An array of Triangle is made, named as tr and the input is passed to the function sort_by_area.
My approach is to apply bubble sort on this array.But instead of comparing tr[j] > tr[j+1] like we do in normal bubble sort, I'm comparing the areas of tr[j] and tr[j+1]. Now, if area of tr[j] > tr[j+1]: Swap.

The problem: In the end the results are wrong. The array doesn't sort properly. First I thought it's a typo somewhere so I rewrite the code but the problem persists.

```
double area (int a, int b, int c)
{
 double  p = (a+b+c)/2;
 return sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
}

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
/**
* Sort an array a of the length n
*/
int i,j;
double area1, area2;
triangle temp;
for(i = 0; i < n-1;++i)
{ 
    for(j = 0; j < n-i-1; ++j)
    {
        area1 = area(tr[j].a , tr[j].b, tr[j].c);
        area2 = area(tr[j+1].a , tr[j+1].b, tr[j+1].c);
        if(area1 > area2)
        {
            temp = tr[j];
            tr[j] = tr[j+1];
            tr[j+1] = temp;
        } 
    }
}

}
```

input: 20

23 37 47
22 18 5
58 31 31
28 36 40
54 62 11
31 41 14
53 18 54
41 38 55
55 44 44
44 48 18
26 41 65
20 23 21
58 61 50
28 56 56
20 39 32
33 45 49
26 41 62
31 46 39
48 49 67
57 33 45

expected output:
22 18 5
31 41 14
20 23 21
54 62 11
26 41 65
58 31 31
20 39 32
26 41 62
44 48 18
23 37 47
53 18 54
28 36 40
31 46 39
33 45 49
57 33 45
28 56 56
41 38 55
55 44 44
48 49 67
58 61 50

actual output:
22 18 5
54 62 11
31 41 14
20 23 21
26 41 65
20 39 32
58 31 31
26 41 62
23 37 47
44 48 18
53 18 54
28 36 40
31 46 39
33 45 49
57 33 45
28 56 56
41 38 55
55 44 44
48 49 67
58 61 50

Comment: Your indexing is wrong in the inner loop. For a bubble sort you want to check element `i` against each element between `i + 1` and `n - 1` but here you are checking against each element between 0 and `n - i - 1`. Either change the inner loop range or add `i` to the array indexing for the second item.

Comment: Also take care that `(a+b+c)/2` is _integer division_ and will calculate incorrect areas if `a+b+c` is odd; divide by `2.0` instead to ensure floating-point division.

Comment: Don't calculate the area (you don't care what the area is, you only care if the area will be larger or smaller). Note that, for positive numbers, if `sqrt(a) < sqrt(b)` is true then `a < b` will also be true (in other words, you could calculate "area squared" and use that instead).

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you, but I still don't get it. Should I write (j=i+1;j<n-1;++j)?

Comment: @TypeIA I actually looked up a couple of websites and they all write bubble sort similarly. Here are links for reference: www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/ and www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort I don't understand what wrong in my implementation and will be really grateful if you can lead me with an example. Thanks.

Comment: Your ranges are more complex than necessary, but look correct.  Your `p` calculation is slightly wrong but it shouldn't cause the problem that you indicate.  Maybe the problem is in some other part of the code that you are not showing?  The input or output?  Alternately, try dividing by `2.0` and/or eliminating the `sqrt`.  Perhaps this is a casting error.

Comment: @mdfst13 it works fine for n<=10. This is the next test case for n = 20 the output is broken. Do you think there is a memory management issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for this challenge:

```
double area(triangle t){
    double p = (t.a+t.b+t.c)/2.0;
    return sqrt(p*(p-t.a)*(p-t.b)*(p-t.c));
}

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(area(tr[j]) < area(tr[i])){
                triangle temp = tr[i];
                tr[i]=tr[j];
                tr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your usage of the 'for' loop for comparing triangles is this (by triangle, I mean triangle's area):

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i){
    ...
    ...
    for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j){
        ...
    }
}
```

Observe carefully: The loop you used fails to compare the last elements of the arrays.

Comment: Maybe it would __help more to explain__ how you approached the problem, using comments to share your knowledge. Designing effective algorithms is a result of thinking and applying rules. These contribute to a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I try the explain with my bad English :) I hope this is usefully :)

Answer (score 0):

I just improvised your code and it works:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < math.h >

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
float area(int a, int b, int c)
{
    float p;
    p = (float)(a + b + c) / 2;
    return sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
}
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    float area1, area2;
    triangle temp[5];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            area1 = area(tr[j].a, tr[j].b, tr[j].c);
            area2 = area(tr[j + 1].a, tr[j + 1].b, tr[j + 1].c);
            if (area1 > area2)
            {
                temp[0] = tr[j];
                tr[j] = tr[j + 1];
                tr[j + 1] = temp[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle* tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Code only answers are seen as low quality.  Could you add some text to clarify?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: I wish i could add text but I'm new to Stack Overflow and I don't know to give answers . Even I had to managed a lot to write those code .

Comment: @MadhavMishra Then you should read [ask] and keep-on answering... your effort is appreciated!

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

An edit of @Zümrüd-ü Anka's answer to match the bubble sorts you'll find elsewhere. Your loops actually should work fine, both for loops here are the same as yours. This passes the test cases for HackerRank. I think it was actually just the integer division that was giving you an issue.

```
double area(triangle t){
    double p = (t.a+t.b+t.c)/2.0;
    return sqrt(p*(p-t.a)*(p-t.b)*(p-t.c));
}

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
            if(area(tr[j]) > area(tr[j+1])){
                triangle temp = tr[j+1];
                tr[j+1]=tr[j];
                tr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```